# In VirtualBox swapping between Console and X11 Windows

Tags: x11, virtualbox

Im running a VirtualBox Image, but it only shows a single console window, how can I get an X11 Windowing environment ?

I didnt build the image myself Im using one pre-provided and its not at all clear whether it can run with a Gui environment or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the virtual machine I have just contains a server only install without any graphical packages installed, so the problem is a function of the linux installation whereas I was thinking there was an option I needed to enable in the virtual machine itself.

FYI something like

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

may do the trick, but in my particular case ran for ages, ground my machine down to a standstill and then gave up.

Mission aborted.